# How do you quantify the success of a billboard?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

For example if an internet company puts up a billboard for 3 weeks in a city with the words "Try our product". How do we statistically quantify this ad worked? Let's use website traffic as our metric. My thought was to use a 1 sample t-test of the website traffic during the billboard campaign against the regional website traffic average. I wondering if this satisfies the assumptions for a 1 sample t-test, and if there are other ways to quantify the success of billboard (ex. measuring affects later on).

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but the way I would go about it would be to gather data from a few months before the billboard was placed to see the factors affecting site traffic. 
Site traffic tends to be seasonal, based on the type of website. Once you have a decent idea of the impact of other factors, look at the current model including the effect of billboard placement and the beta coefficient.

Further an F-test or T-test ( based on the distribution of your data) will tell you the effect of it.